# Basic principle to measure length between two points using a single camera

Tags: image-processing, augmented-reality

What is the basic principle for creating a virtual measuring app, given that I have normal camera, or bunch of cameras focused on a single object from different angles. So basically how to measure the distance between two physical points in a video without knowing anything else.

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer: You can't do that.

The size of a pixel in object space depends on the distance to the camera.

Either you need depth information which is not available using a single standard camera or you need to know the size of a known object in the same distance. But the second doesn't work in most real world scenarios.

With a well known setup of multiple cameras you can do stereo vision.

Comment: okay, suppose I have multiple cameras, and provision to put them in any place I want, what would be the way to do it then? (basically how to implement stereo vision)

Comment: I guess you don't know what you are asking here. otherwise you wouldn't ask.I think you should learn how to get information from the internet and books. or maybe get a degree in computer vision.